# Solving single objective optimization using multi objective algorithm

Tags: optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I want to use multi objective evolutionary algorithm to solve a single objective optimization problem. Is it technically correct and how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi objective algorithms typically work by comparing fitness scores.  But when the fitness scores are multi-objective, how can you compare them?  Hence, the magic is often in how the algorithm sorts fitness scores.  With a single-objective, this magic may be lost when trying to optimize using a multi-objective algorithm, but all the same, it will probably still work quite well.

Since you're only optimizing a single objective, you can get away with utilizing genetic algorithms at their simplest.  For an example of that, refer to my answer over at [AI algorithm for multi dimension solution optimization / prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584964/ai-algorithm-for-multi-dimension-solution-optimization-prediction).

Comment: Joe, thanks for the answer. I actually required to optimize a profit function, so I split it into two sub-function of income and expense. I am using SPEA2 for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add something to the previous answer. Multi-objective optimization is a generalization of single-objective optimization. This implies that single-objective optimization is a **subset** of it. The research field in multi-objective optimization addresses the difficulty of having more than one value, which implies not a scalar but a vector in the objective space to be used for performance evaluation. Every multi-objective optimization algorithm has to address this in order to work.

For single-objective optimization the **domination concept** in the objective space obviously still holds. In bi-objective optimization (assuming minimization) we say that `[3, 5]` is dominated by `[2, 4]` (because it is better in both objectives) and indifferent to `[4, 2]` (once better and once worse). In single-objective optimization we basically compare just a list with a **single** element which is the same as just comparing a scalar. We simply say *3* dominates *5*.

Therefore, you can in general also run multi-objective optimization algorithms on a single-objective problem. However, you might find better single-objective algorithms which converge faster.

For instance, you can use the well-known NSGA-II algorithm to optimize a single-objective function using [pymoo](https://pymoo.org), a multi-objective optimization framework in Python.

**Disclaimer:** I am the main developer of [pymoo](https://pymoo.org).

The source code below uses NSGA-II (a multi-objective algorithm) to obtain the optimal solution for the Himmelblau function (a single-objective test problem):

```
from pymoo.algorithms.nsga2 import NSGA2
from pymoo.factory import get_problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize

problem = get_problem("himmelblau")

algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=20)

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)

print(res.F)
```

which finds `F=0.00034225` in 2000 function evaluations.

However, if you use `Hooke and Jeeves Pattern Search` you will obtain the optimum much faster:

```
from pymoo.algorithms.so_pattern_search import PatternSearch
from pymoo.factory import get_problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize

problem = get_problem("himmelblau")

algorithm = PatternSearch()

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)

print(res.F)
```

Found `F=4.62182083e-18` in only 224 evaluations.